# add items to a listbox in a function (Delphi 7)

Tags: function, delphi, listbox, delphi-7

I would like to write a function that checks if a certain letter is in a certain word.

That is the current function (sry for the german)

```
function woistderbuchstabe (wort, buchstabe:String):String;
VAR i: Integer;
begin
for i:=1 to length(wort) do
  if wort[i]=buchstabe then
    showmessage(INTtoSTR(i))
    //LB_ausgabe.items.add(INTtoSTR(i));
end;
```

The way it's written now the function actually works. It shows one or several messages with the position(s) of the letter searched for (the variable "buchstabe") in the word "wort". E.g. for wort=abctc and buchstabe=c it shows 3 and 5.

But if i would write it this way

```
function woistderbuchstabe (wort, buchstabe:String):String;
VAR i: Integer;
begin
for i:=1 to length(wort) do
  if wort[i]=buchstabe then
    LB_ausgabe.items.add(INTtoSTR(i));
end;
```

(remove the showmessage and make the ListBox thing actual code)

then I get the error

> Undefined Identifier: 'LB_ausgabe'

This is the complete code of the Unit

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    E_kette: TEdit;
    E_buchstabe: TEdit;
    B_start: TButton;
    LB_ausgabe: TListBox;
    procedure B_startClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


function woistderbuchstabe (wort, buchstabe:String):String;
VAR i: Integer;
begin
for i:=1 to length(wort) do
  if wort[i]=buchstabe then
    showmessage(INTtoSTR(i))
    //LB_ausgabe.items.add(INTtoSTR(i));
end;

procedure TForm1.B_startClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
woistderbuchstabe (E_kette.text, E_buchstabe.text);
end;

end.
```

Pls try to be specific as I'm pretty clueless about Delphi.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using the function POS which finds the position of a sub-string within a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `woistderbuchstabe` is not a member of your class `TForm1`... so it doesn't have direct access to it's members unless you specify an instance. I suggest this fix:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    E_kette: TEdit;
    E_buchstabe: TEdit;
    B_start: TButton;
    LB_ausgabe: TListBox;
    procedure B_startClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    function woistderbuchstabe (wort, buchstabe:String):String;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


function TForm1.woistderbuchstabe (wort, buchstabe:String):String;
VAR i: Integer;
begin
for i:=1 to length(wort) do
  if wort[i]=buchstabe then
    LB_ausgabe.items.add(INTtoSTR(i));
end;

procedure TForm1.B_startClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
woistderbuchstabe (E_kette.text, E_buchstabe.text);
end;

end.
```

But you can also just reference your `Form1: TForm1` instance (global variable), in your function (I recommend you stick with the OO approach, though):

```
Form1.LB_ausgabe.items.add(INTtoSTR(i));
```

PS: Check `Pos` and `PosEx` functions too, as they are probably (I never benchmarked) faster solution, since they are `asm` implemented.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would probably have to read a little bit more about Delphi to fully understand why this works as we're only using Delphi very superficially in school, but it definitely works.

Comment: @someonesomewhere Delphi is an Object Oriented language, meaning it's widely based on encapsulating things inside an object.  The form (`TForm1`) is also an object, and anything which works with its contents *should* also be within that object to be able to access its members. Imagine a unit which has 5 different objects - each one needs to be self-contained from each other.

Comment: @someonesomewhere this question has very little to do with Delphi, actually. If you can read any introductory text on any object oriented language, you should understand this better. I can't point you to any specific references, though. =/

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if you might need to use this logic from somewhere else, you need to decouple it from your user interface. You can do this by changing your function to a procedure that accepts a more generic class to populate (like a plain old `TStrings`) as a parameter. As `TStrings` is a common base for `TComboBox.Items`, `TListBox.Items`, `TMemo.Lines` and is used in many other places, this seems like the most flexible way to accomplish what you want to do.

```
procedure woistderbuchstabe (List: TStrings; wort, buchstabe:String);
VAR i: Integer;
begin
for i := 1 to length(wort) do
  if wort[i] = buchstabe then
    List.Add(InttoStr(i));
end;
```

This allows you to use the procedure with your `TListBox` (call it with `LB_ausgabe.items`, a `TMemo`, using `Memo1.Lines`, a `TComboBox` with `Combobox1.Items`, a `TRichEdit` with `RichEdit1.Lines`, or a plain old `TStringList` directly with `SL`.

You can now call it from anywhere you want, such as a `TForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject)`, using `ListBox1.Items`, or a standalone method that creates and passes in a `TStringList`. It's not tied to a specific form, so it's more flexible and able to be reused elsewhere.